# $G$ is a non cyclic group of order $51$ , does it mean $\forall a \in G$ , $a^{34} = e$?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

$G$ is a non cyclic group of order $51$ , does it mean $\forall a \in G$ , $a^{34} = e$?

**My proof:**
I assumed that $o(a) = 34$. then I said that $1,2,17,34$ can divide it.

Then $1,17$ are prime numbers so if $o(a)$ is one of them, it means they are cycic which isn't possible. 
and about $2,34$ it also not possible because of lagrange $o(a) | o(G)$ won't be true because $2 | 51, 34 | 51$ not true.

**My teachers proof:**
The teacher told me I'm wrong and I needed to go from $51$ and find its divisors $(1,3,17)$  and $a^3 = a$ so $a^{34} = (a^3)^{11} \cdot a = a$, then showing a counter example such as $Z_3$ X $Z_{17}$.

Do you think what I wrote is correct?

**EDIT:** I just noticed there's a post about that question, but I still want to know if going from the assumption can be possible.

Comment: Not following your logic. You start by assuming that the order of $a$ is $34$, which (as you point out) is not possible.  But that wasn't the claim.

Comment: @lulu Why it is not possible to assume of the order of $a$ is 34?

Comment: You can assume it, but so what?  We quickly see that it is impossible, so we have learned nothing.  In the cyclic group of order $17$, for example, it is perfectly true that $a^{34}=e\,\forall a$.

Comment: @lulu That's the point, it is perfectly true. but it can't be possible because it will mean that the group will have to be cyclic because 17 is a prime number. and given that the group isn't cyclic.

Comment: Not following at all, sorry.  I don't think your proof makes any sense.

Comment: Okay, thank you. @lulu

Comment: $C_{17}$ then is cyclic, but why should $G$ then by cyclic? Also non-cyclic groups can have $C_{17}$ as a subgroup.

Comment: Just to say:  the actual theorem is vacuously true, as there are no non-cyclic groups of order $51$.  The teacher's supposed counterexample is cyclic, so that doesn't work.  The theorem is true because it admits no counterexamples.  For the same reason it is true that $a^{29}=e$ for all $a$ in the group.  As the "group" does not exist, there is no $a$ to supply a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $C_3\times C_{17}\cong C_{51}$, which is cyclic. So this cannot be a counterexample. An important information is that every abelian group of order $51$ *is* already cyclic, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353498/noncyclic-abelian-group-of-order-51), and in fact all groups of order $51$ are cyclic, because $51=pq$ and $p\nmid q-1$.

Edit: About your proof, we have that $17\mid 51$, so that $G$ has an element of order $17$. Why does it imply that $G$ is cyclic? You need to do more here.

Comment: I'm asking here (even twice +1 in edit) if my proof is correct.

Comment: Typo:  $3\times 17=51$, not $54$.  Also:  since $3\nmid (17-1)$, all groups of order $51$ are cyclic.

Comment: @lulu you mean $3 \nmid 17$

Comment: @lulu Ah, that's what i just realized, thank you.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  No....  Sylow, and [a little work](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_Groups_of_Order_pq) tells us that all groups of order $pq$ where $p<q$ are primes such that $p\nmid (q-1)$ are cyclic.

Comment: @lulu ah, thanks for that

Comment: Your (or @Lulu's) argument shows that the claim is (vacuously) true :-) Every element $a$ of every non-cyclic group of order $51$, indeed, satisfies the equation $a^{34}=e$!